# JavaScript move array element to end of array

Tags: javascript, angularjs, lodash

**EDIT - 3 elegant solutions**

Three solutions, from odinho, Pranav and Bekim. Thanks, tested and worked perfectly.

**One (@odinho - very cool)**

```
data.push(...data.splice(data.findIndex(v => v.name == 'other'), 1))
```

**Two (also great one liner)**

```
for(var x in data)data[x].name == "other" ? data.push( data.splice(x,1)[0] ) : 0;
```

**Three**

```
   var res = data.slice(),
   len = res.length;

    for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        if (res[i].name == 'other') {
            res.push(res.splice(i, 1)[0]);
            i--;
            len--;
        }
    }
```

**JS TOOLS IM USING**

Angular 1.5.6, lodash 4.1x

Here is the scenario I have an array of objects sorted alphabetically e.g. sortedData below etc.. However, within that array is also the catch all `Other` which is obviously sorted alphabetically as well. I want to remove other from the array and then move to the end of array without messing with the current sorted array.

**NOTE**

My current approach below works but is ugly. Does JS, angular or lodash have something more elegant?

```
var data = [
    {id:1,name:'apple'},
    {id:2,name:'banana'},
    {id:3,name:'other'},
    {id:4,name:'tomato'},
    {id:5,name:'strawberry'}
];

function move(array, fromIndex, toIndex) {
    array.splice(toIndex, 1, array.splice(fromIndex, 1)[0]);
    return array;
}

var moved = move(
    data,
    _.findIndex(data, ['name', 'other']),
    Object.keys(data).length
);
```

**Ideal Outcome**

```
 var data = [
        {id:1,name:'one'},
        {id:2,name:'two'},
        {id:4,name:'four'},
        {id:5,name:'five'}
        {id:3,name:'other'},
    ]
```

Comment: You can make a copy of the `data` array with ``var copy = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data));``

Comment: You could copy the info, splice the array, then push the array.  Or, as @e4en just posted, as I commented, you can make it a one liner to remove the copying of the info.

Comment: Is the array presorted, or are you sorting it, then afterwards, moving that one specific element?

If you are sorting it, you could just write a custom sort that always returns that one object at the very end.

Comment: @Alan I tried the sort approach with lodash but I keep running into issues and frankly couldn't get it work. Best I got was added twice ... original spot and end

Comment: I don't see any elegance on Pranav solution, I see overhead and confusion making the whole process at least 300% times slower than necessary, knowing that these kind of operations are slow by design, adding three self assignable incremental variables is a bit too much of unnecessary processing to an already not so fast native JavaScript array splice method. (and to be correct in your citation you need to switch the order of author names respectively to their corresponding js expressions / declarations).

Comment: @BekimBacaj : https://jsfiddle.net/pranavcbalan/90vwyw1j/ :)

Comment: Just by the way, I'm a bit confused... why have You included solutions in Your question? I personally would rather comment an answer than edit a question and include it there.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You do Array.findIndex in pure Javascript (ES6), without using any libs:

```
data.push(data.splice(data.findIndex(v => v.name == 'other'), 1)[0])
```

[Array.findIndex is new](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex), but most browsers people actually use these days have it. So you can probably use it. (Edge supports it, but not IE).

If you find the `[0]` ugly, you can use spread to unpack the array (that way it'll also work for more than one item with some changes):

```
data.push(...data.splice(data.findIndex(v => v.name == 'other'), 1))
```

Comment: ES6 is very good for a website you like to show to your friends when they come over at your place.

Comment: ES6 is good for writing nicer code in production for anything. Either server side or frontend with babel :)

Comment: @odinho-Velmont love the one liner. Very neat. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

A plain (Vanilla) JavaScript will do just fine:

```
 for(var x in data)data[x].name == "other" ? data.push( data.splice(x,1)[0] ) : 0;
```

```js
var data = [
    {id:1,name:'apple'},
    {id:2,name:'banana'},
    {id:3,name:'other'},
    {id:4,name:'tomato'},
    {id:5,name:'strawberry'}
];

for(var x in data)data[x].name == "other" ? data.push( data.splice(x,1)[0] ) : 0;


console.log( data );
```

Comment: I'd like to report to the admins that this perfectly compact code and henceforth beautiful power solution, has been a consecutive target of 17 negative votes, delt arbitrarily and simply on the basis of hate in an attempt of damaging my reputation. 

Hence are zero comments demonstrating zero weakness of my giveaway one-liner.
But I don't know how! Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Use simple [for loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for)

```js
var data = [{
  id: 1,
  name: 'apple'
}, {
  id: 2,
  name: 'banana'
}, {
  id: 3,
  name: 'other'
}, {
  id: 4,
  name: 'tomato'
}, {
  id: 5,
  name: 'strawberry'
}];

// store the length of array  
var len = data.length;

// iterate over all array elements
for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
  // check value is `other`
  if (data[i].name == 'other') {
    // if value is other then move the object
    data.push(data.splice(i, 1)[0]);
    // decrement i since the element removed
    i--;
    // decrement len to avoid moved element
    len--;
  }
}

console.log(data);
```

Comment: Aside, the unnecessary overhead imposed to js engine, the code clumsiness and completely unjustified power + time consumption  this is not what the OP is asking for at all. You are NOT reordering the target element in the array of interest, but creating and recreating a new array leaving the target array / the array of interest untouched and in the same state it already was. Meaning, your "solution" begging for a down-vote (  which at this point, I will not bother giving ).